# delete query in c# for deleting selected row

Tags: c#, sql, delete-row

I used following code for deleting record from my SQL server database but this query deleted all my records. I want to delete just the selected row, not all of them.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id=id ", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query. Perhaps, you should check your ID column in the database. I think all the rows have the same ID.

Comment: `where id=id` means match all rows where the ID field of that row is equal to the id field of that row. In other words, match all rows. You need a parameter.. `where id = @id` and then provide the appropriate value

Comment: but i want to delete the selected row from my DataGridView but its deleting all the record.

Comment: `id=id` always give you a true, so all records are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer param id, my friend. Refer the code below:

```
var Id = ""; //set the value that you want to delete

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id=@Id ", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```